# Long to wide format for simple dataframe

Tags: r, format, tidyr, transpose

I have a dataset like this:

```
df <- data.frame(origin = c('A', 'B', 'C'), freq = c(100,3000,200))

  origin freq
1      A  100
2      B 3000
3      C  200
```

I want to convert this to a structure like this:

```
A   B    C
100 3000 200
```

So that I can `cbind` it to an existing dataframe

---

1. **`tidyr::spread()`** 
   I tried using `tidyr::spread` however this would require the rows to have unique IDs. I can do this however this won't give me the desired result:

   `> df %>% mutate(id = row_number()) %>% spread(origin, freq)
     id   A    B   C
   1  1 100   NA  NA
   2  2  NA 3000  NA
   3  3  NA   NA 200`
2. **`t()`** 
   I can transpose the dataframe, however then it will convert `origin` to a row instead of column names. Of course I can edit it by setting the column names manually but this seems way to cumbersome.

   `as.data.frame(t(df))
            V1   V2   V3
   origin    A    B    C
   freq    100 3000  200`

Comment: I am not getting the same thing, when I run rownames( data.frame( t ( df )) ) origin and freq are rownames

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could add a temporary column before `spread`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(n = 1) %>%
  spread(origin, freq) %>%
  select(-n)

#   A    B   C
#1 100 3000 200
```

If you have newer version of `tidyr`, we can use `pivot_wider` instead of `spread`

```
df %>%
  mutate(n = 1) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = origin, values_from = freq) %>%
  select(-n)
```

---

We could also reconstruct the dataframe

```
data.frame(matrix(df$freq, ncol = nrow(df), dimnames = list(NULL, df$origin)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are some alternatives.

Note that the `origin` column is sorted in the example but if it were not then the `setNames`, `dcast` and `dplyr` alternatives preserve the ordering while the other alternatives sort them and you may want one or the other behavior.

**1) xtabs** We can use `xtabs` to convert `df` to an object of class `c("xtabs", "table")` and from that to `"data.frame"`.  Omit `as.data.frame.list` if table output is ok.  No packages are used.

```
as.data.frame.list(xtabs(freq ~ origin, df))
##     A    B   C
## 1 100 3000 200
```

**1a) tapply** We could use `tapply` in much the same way:

```
as.data.frame.list(tapply(df$freq, df$origin, c))
##     A    B   C
## 1 100 3000 200
```

**1b) setNames** Also `setNames` can be used in much the same way.

```
as.data.frame.list(setNames(df$freq, df$origin))
##     A    B   C
## 1 100 3000 200
```

**2) split** Another approach is to split the `freq` by `origin` giving a list and then convert that list to a data.frame.  Again, no packages are used.

```
as.data.frame(split(df$freq, df$origin))
##     A    B   C
## 1 100 3000 200
```

**3) reshape** We could use `reshape` like this.  The `setNames` line could be omitted if we are not fussy about the form of the names.

```
wide <- reshape(transform(df, id = 1), dir = "wide", timevar = "origin")[-1]
setNames(wide, df$origin)
##     A    B   C
## 1 100 3000 200
```

**4) dcast** This solution uses the data.table package -- there is also a `dcast` in the reshape2 package that works similarly.

```
library(data.table)

dcast(df, . ~ origin, value.var = "freq")
##     A    B   C
## 1 100 3000 200
```

**5) dplyr/tibble**.  Using the indicated packages we remove the rownames (only needed if the data frame has row names but doesn't hurt if not), convert the `origin` column to row names, transpose what is left and convert that to a `tibble`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

df %>%
  remove_rownames %>%
  column_to_rownames("origin") %>%
  t %>%
  as.tibble

## # A tibble: 1 x 3
##       A     B     C
##   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
## 1   100  3000   200
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use for row names the first column and then transpose without it.

```
t(`rownames<-`(df,df[,1])[-1])
#        A    B   C
# freq 100 3000 200
```